# How could you accomplish the following transformation in sufficient yield?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've considered Riley oxidation but the major product would have a hydroxyl group at the benzylic carbon to the left of the double bond instead of the methyl group as shown. Is there a way to make the reaction favor oxidation of the methyl group?[image]

Comment: This is really not straightforward. Any conditions you choose are likely to react at one of the benzylic sites and aromatise the top ring.

Comment: The structure shown is similar to dronabinol which has an allylic group and a benzopyran ring. There is another drug called nabilone in which the allylic methyl group is oxiidized to the cyclohexanone. Search for these 2 compounds in the literature may give you some idea that will inspire you.

Comment: I'm thinking a Pd catalysed allylic acetoxylation might work as the methyl group is the least hindered site for attack. I don't think it would go exclusively at that point though.

Answer (score 4):

As has been stated by @Beerhunter those benzylic hydrogens are a serious concern . Nonetheless, here is a different offering. To solubilize carboxylic acid **1** both the phenolic group and the acid should be protected. Here, both of the groups are protected as methyl groups. [An ester group and silylated (TBS?) phenol would also suffice.] The double bond of **2** is epoxided to **3**. The critical step is the isomerization of the epoxide to an exo-methylene allylic alcohol. There are several reagents that do this transformation. Yamamoto<sup>1</sup> has shown that methyl groups are more reactive than methylene groups with the epoxide rearranging reagent diethyl aluminum 2,2,6,6-tetramethyl piperidide although no benzylic methylene examples were provided. 
Acetylation of the allylic alcohol affords allylic acetate **4**. Grieco<sup>2</sup> has reported that *bis*-acetonitrile PdCl<sub>2</sub> isomerizes allylic acetates to their tautomer in what is an equilibrium reaction favoring the more stable isomer. In this instance, the trisubstituted, endocyclic double bond compound **5** is expected. The remaining steps involve removal of the protecting groups of choice to afford the target **6**.
[image]
1) S. Tanaka, A. Yasuda, H. Yamamoto and H. Nozaki, *J. Am. Chem. Soc*., **1975**, *97*, 3252.

2) P. A. Grieco, T. Takigawa, S. L. Bongers and H. Tanaka, *J. Am. Chem. Soc*., **1980**, *102*, 7587.

Comment: I like this answer, but fear for the atom economy of the sequence.

Comment: @Beerhunter: At this point, I don't think atom economy is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The methods required are generally outside of the mainstream lab chemistry,  but that does not mean they can't be used in lab setups.

As Waylander states, use of oxygen with acetic acid can be catalysed to acetyloxylate the molecule. Then the acetate ester is simply cleaved.

The main issue in this molecule is the activated benzylic position. These are usually prone to oxidation without trying. So most methods suggested may also functionalise this benzylic position too:
Radical bromination with NBS and an initiator; biocatalysts; singlet oxygen.

If bromination is used,  one could deliberately exhaustively react until the allylic position is functionalise, then selectively reduce the benzylic position - this is possible using catalytic hydrogenation or transfer hydrogenation through careful catalyst and condition selection.

A bit more fiddly is using singlet oxygen.  The best method to use this is through flow rather than batch methods (also safer). However,  formation of allylic hydroperoxides from allylic functionality is well documented. A reductive step then needs to take place to yield the alcohol. Sulfides and triphenylphosphine are usually cited but other methods are possible.

All the methods above are at least two steps though apart from biocatalysis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an organic chemist, but upon looking for similar systems I found a nice collection of various papers that all use selenium dioxide, so allylic oxidation as you mentioned it with various other functional groups. I copied the sections from the papers (therefore sorry for the quality and the Chinese in one paper) together with the preparations.

To me this looks like the most promising route here. According to that mechanism it should favor the allylic position here selectively and therefore and also due to sterics hopefully not oxidize the longer alkyl chain.

[image]

Comment: Riley oxidation is SeO2 oxidation.

Comment: None of the examples you quote have the adjacent aromatic ring which makes things much more difficult.

Comment: How would that ring influence it? I can't really see any delocalization of the benzene ring into the other ring. So it probably only causes some minor effects on the electron density in the double bond.

Comment: Did you read question properly? There are 3 allylic postiton - 2 of which are also benzylic, and OP wants OH in the one which isn't. Probably undoable in single step.

Comment: @Justanotherchemist  Look at the starting structure; it is a dihydronaphthalene. Show it an oxidising agent and it will aromatise. That is what makes this challenging. If I was tasked with making the target structure I would not start from here!